# Preventing cross site scripting attack on flash container pages

Tags: apache-flex, xss

I have a website with a flex application. The flex application has no user input - except for clicks for navigation. The website also uses no scripting language - i.e. no php, asp, jsp or cfm.

The website just consists of one page which contains the flash file for the flex application. The source code of this page is here: http://pastebin.com/n5b4RxqT

I have been advised (by a software program used by my client) that this website is vulnerable to a reflective type XSS attack and have been advised to 'sanitize' all user input.

I am a noob with respect to XSS and would respectfully like to ask that AFAIK there is no user input. What should I sanitize and how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using AC_OETags is the old way of doing things and is deprecated.  What you want to do is use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) which is now the default in Flash Builder 4.